# Pass json keyfile from cloud storage to ServiceAccountCredentials function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have the following few lines of code

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    filename,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'])
```

A `filename` is expected. My json key is stored in Google Cloud storage. How do I return the filename so I can pass it to the ServiceAccountCredentials assuming my bucket is named `bucket_name` and my key is name `json.key`

So far I'm stuck with this:

```
bucket = read_storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob("key.json")
json_data_string = blob.download_as_string()
```

I can print the `json_data_string`:

```
{\n "type": "service_account",\n "project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",\n "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",\n "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQ=\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n",\n "client_email": "xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",\n "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",\n "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",\n "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",\n "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",\n "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxxxxx"\n}
```

How should I use this `json_data_string` variable? how can I pass it the `ServiceAccountCredentials` function. I'm not sure what is really this `json_data_string` variable.

Comment: is your code is running on Google Cloud? or elsewhere?

Comment: Running on Cloud function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuck because you need a credential to have the capability to download your JSON key. "You need a json key for downloading the json key". Quite absurd, no?

The other solution is to make your bucket public: A secret key in a publicly accessible bucket. Also absurd...

This is because, it's not the right way. You can deploy a function with a service account, it's named [function identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity). This solution will make your code far more simpler.

First, you don't need to get the service account key file from storage, because it's automatically loaded with your function.

Second, because the service account is automatically loaded into the function, you can simply use the default credential in your code

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.create_scoped(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'])
```

Let me know if you need more.

**EDIT**

*I let the first part because I strongly recommend you to not use JSON key file in GCP platform environment. It's horrible to manage: you have to store it securely, you have to rotate it regularly (recommended every 90 days),... If you really want to use it, try [secret manager to store and retrieve it safely](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-java)*

So, to unlock you (because it's the heart of your question), you can have a look to [the documentation](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html) of the python class. You can see a method named `from_json()`. But this method doesn't allow scope definition. If you want to use scope, you can use this one `from_json_keyfile_dict()`. Thereby, I will do something like this

```
bucket = read_storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob("key.json")
json_data_string = blob.download_as_string()

import json
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    json.loads(json_data_string),
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'])
```

*Note: you can download your JSON file stored in Cloud Storage thanks to the default service account used by Cloud Function. It's the [compute engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account) that I don't recommend you to use for 2 reasons: First it's widely open (it is Project Editor), Second, all the services use this default service account if nothing special is defined, execpt some rare services (Scheduler or pubsub for example)*

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my questions. I'm able to access the information in my JSON key as I'm able to print them. Let me know if you can modify your answer based on my update. Otherwise I feel like I'm a bit lost with your answer.

Comment: Of course, you asked for red, I answer green!! Despite my strong recommendation to do differently, I think I have answer your first problem. Let me know if it work now

Answer (score 0):

I came to this Q&A because I needed a Google Cloud Function (GCF) to access a Google Sheet.

Assuming that the GCF would need to be authenticated with a JSON credentials file, I was looking for an efficient way to pass the JSON credentials file to the GCF.

In their answer, Guillaume Blaquiere's wrote:

> ...you don't need to get the service account key file from storage, because it's automatically loaded with your function.

Based on that I was able to access Google Sheets using a GCF with the following snippet:

```
import gspread
from google.auth import default
    
credentials, project_id = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    
# Open the Google Sheet 'Firestore Connector'
google_sheet = gc.open_by_key(google_sheet_id).worksheet(google_worksheet_name)
```

Hope you find this useful.